# Check if the textfields is null in Jquery

Tags: jquery

Im trying to check if the textfields is null using jquery, but its not working, The textfields is dynamically created and has name quiztxtBox[], with bracket, indicating it is an array, and when a certain field is null the textfield will turn red,. but the problem is it is not working, hmmm
Here is my codes

```
$("#quiztxtBox[]").each(function()
              {
                  if($("#quiztxtBox[]").val()=="")
                  {
                      $("#quiztxtBox[]").nextAll('span').html("Field needs filling");
                      $("#quiztxtBox[]").css({"background-color":"#f6d9d4"});

                  }
          });
```

**EDIT** 
This is the html codes, the span part is not working, I wonder why, this is the html for dynamically creating textboxes..

```
<div id="QuestionTBDiv1" >
                                        <label>Question</label><br/>
                                        <input type="text" name="quiztxtBox[]" size="57" id="quiztxtBox[]" placeholder="Question #1"><br/>
                                        <label>Answer</label><br/>
                                        <input type="text" name="quiztxtBox[]" size="24" id="answer[]" placeholder="Choice A">&nbsp;<input type="radio" class = "choiceA" name="correct_answer1" value="A">&nbsp;
                                        <input type="text" name="quiztxtBox[]" size="24" id="answer[]" placeholder="Choice B">&nbsp;<input type="radio" class = "choiceB" name="correct_answer1" value="B"><br/>
                                        <input type="text" name="quiztxtBox[]" size="24" id="answer[]" placeholder="Choice C">&nbsp;<input type="radio" class = "choiceC" name="correct_answer1" value="C">&nbsp;
                                        <input type="text" name="quiztxtBox[]" size="24" id="answer[]" placeholder="Choice D">&nbsp;<input type="radio" class = "choiceD" name="correct_answer1" value="D"><br>
                                        <span name="errMchoice" class="errorMsg"></span>
                                        </div>
```

Comment: "has name quiztxtBox[]" - name or id?

Comment: attribute selector `$('input[name="quiztxtBox[]"]')`??

Comment: @ArunPJohny you should consider answering this way as of OP comments to the answer this works perfect.

Comment: Note that no matter what selector you use, `.val()` will only ever return the value of the first element in the selector's elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
$("[name='quiztxtBox[]']").each(function(){
  if ($(this).is(':empty')) {
    $(this).nextAll('span').html("Field needs filling");
    $(this).css({"background-color":"#f6d9d4"});
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, this works except for this part $(this).nextAll('span').html("Field needs filling");

Comment: @user2901740 I don't see your HTML, so I cannot help you/

Comment: well, it is consist ko 4 textbox and 1 span tag, 4 textbox and 1 tag so on .. How I wish I can post it here.. hmm

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

change id to class that is, change **id="#quiztxtBox[]"**  to **class=".quiztxtBox"** then,

```
$(".quiztxtBox").each(function()
{
    if($(this).val()=="")
    {
         $(this).nextAll('span').html("Field needs filling");
         $(this).css({"background-color":"#f6d9d4"});
    }
});
```

i think you need this:

check demo @ http://jsfiddle.net/renishar/S73gq/